# What's the simplest way to make all my controls in my root UIView scroll?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, ios

I have a `ViewController` that manages a view full of controls, including `UITextView`s, `UIButton`s, and a drawing view.  It's far more than I can fit on the screen, but I'd like my design to have it all in one place and make the root view scrollable.  I've become very spoiled with Interface Builder automating much of the coding work for me.  Is there a way to add a `UIScrollView` to my root `UIView` and then attach all my other controls/views to that `UIScrollView` and let IB automate the functionality to make it all scroll when the user swipes their finger?  If not, what's the simplest way to make all my controls in my root `UIView` scroll vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make a UIScrollView the root view for your view controller, and then attach your composed view as a subview of the scroll view. The scroll view will take care of the rest.